# Web.Security.Membership and Web.Security.Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, roleprovider

I am currently using Web.Security.Membership and Web.Security.Roles. For some reason Membership always produces the expected results but Roles seems to be a problem. When debugging the following code the result is different for roleExists1 and roleExists2.

```
bool roleExists1 = Roles.RoleExists("Administrator");
bool valid = Membership.ValidateUser(emailAddress, password);
bool roleExists2 = Roles.RoleExists("Administrator");
```

Can anyone suggest why roleExists1 is 'true' and roleExists2 is 'false'?

Comment: too few info, only reason in given context could be that Membership.ValidateUser creates the role

Comment: what is your membership and role provider?  According to MSDN, Roles checks the underlying role data source.  So the expected reason for the failure is a change in that data source.